# Removing properties in mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I'm wrapping material TextField with redux component. Some of the properties should be used in `mapStateToProps` only and not passed to a component itself. Otherwise, I'm getting `Unknown prop` warning. Specifying undefined value doesn't help.

```
function mapStateToProps(state = {}, ownProps) {
    var dataKey = ownProps.dataKey;
    return {
        value: state[dataKey],
        dataKey: undefined
    }
}
const store = createStore(reducer, {stuff: 123});

const toDraw = <TextInput dataKey="stuff"/>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhuv88ka/)

Is there are any simpler way to remove something from `ownProps` in `mapStateToProps` rather than creating wrapper component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it by supplying a function for connect's 3rd argument `mergeProps`, which defaults to:

```
function mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) {
  return Object.assign({}, ownProps, stateProps, dispatchProps);
}
```

Write your own version that cherry-picks the props you want to send to your component.